# How to compare dates across two tables where one date is valid until updated?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have a relatively complicated query to write; we use Postgres.  Basically, I have data across two tables:

Table 1:  Historical ticket prices

```
ticket_seller_id | show_id | low_price | created_at 
               1 | 17      | 40        | 05/09/2015
               2 | 23      | 50        | 06/23/2015
               2 | 23      | 60        | 07/23/2015
               2 | 23      | 70        | 08/23/2015
               3 | 23      | 55        | 07/22/2015
```

Table 2: Price alerts created by members

```
show_id | Price | user_id | created_at
     17 | 40    | 25      | 02/16/2016
     17 | 40    | 26      | 02/16/2016
     23 | 50    | 25      | 07/24/2015
```

What I want to do is: create a results table which has ONLY price alerts for which the "alert price" was lower than an EXISTING historical price.  From the data above, it would look like this:

```
show_id | Price | user_id | created_at
     17 | 40    | 25      | 02/16/2016
```

Note that the $50 price alert for show 23 from user 25 wouldn't be displayed, because by the time the user created this price alert, the low_price had risen to $60.  Also note that each ticket_seller has its own low_price for each ticket; the answer needs to find the lowest price available from any ticket vendor that was created_at a date prior to the date the alert was created at.  Prices are valid until updated, so the lowest price available for show 23 from seller 2 would be $60 on 8/22/2015, since that's the lowest price at that time.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: And why shouldn't user_id=26 be part of the result? That row was created at the same date with the same price as user_id=25

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are totally right! user_id=26 should be included.   And we are using Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select show_id, price, user_id, created_at
from price_alerts
where price < (
  select price
  from ticket_history
  where show_id = price_alerts.show_id
  and created_at = (
     select max(created_at)
     from ticket_history
     where show_id = price_alerts.show_id
     and created_at < price_alerts.created_at))
```

There are vendor-specific window functions they could be used here, but you have not tagged your question with the database you're using, so this is the vanilla version.

Comment: Thank you!  This got me close enough to figure out the rest of the way on my own.